# NSMutableArray and indexAtObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am a newbie to Objective-C and I am working on getting a good handle in working with arrays.

According to Apples own documentation [`NSMutableArray` inherits from `NSArray`.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I am seeking to use the method `objectAtIndex:i` within a for loop. Yet Xcode is claiming that

> "Property 'objectAtIndex' not found on object of type
>   'NSMutableArray'".

Within a for loop I am performing (or seeking to) the following test:

> if([self.cards objectAtIndex:i].isChosen){
>   do something here }

I am certain I not doing this right. It can be frustrating learning the idiosyncrasies of a new programming language. For me Objective C has, so far, borne little resemblance to C++ or C.

Any pointer or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Walt Williams

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: You should show your @interface where you declare the cards array. Also, once you get the value from your array the type is of id. Using dot syntax to get is chosen won't work. I suggest you get the value from the array and assign it to your object. so Card *card = [self.cards objectAtIndex:i]; then if (card.isChosen) {} // do something

Comment: Oh make sure you have #import'ed the file which defines your classes otherwise the compiler does not know what type it is.

Comment: What is the source file named?  Is it "MyClass.c" or "MyClass.m"?

Comment: (And your error message is contradicting the source you listed.  The compiler would not generate that message (using the word "property" and displaying "objectAtIndex" without the trailing `:`) for a regular method call on a method that accepts a parameter.  Likely the error message is referring to a different line.)

Answer (score 1):

From your error message, you could not be using the method and parameter correctly. Possibly you're trying to use a dot notation?

Your code should be like:

```
id object = [array objectAtIndex:index];
```

where the index comes from your loop and you then use the `object`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Wain's answer, which is correct, but for the sake of completeness, you are using the array and trying to call the method this way:

Ex:

```
array.objectAtIndex.i = 5;  //Java.....?
```

which is the cause of this error:

> "Property 'objectAtIndex' not found on object of type
>   'NSMutableArray'".

It is complaining that you are trying to access a property named "`objectAtIndex`", which of course, doesn't exist.

You mean to call the method:

```
[array objectAtIndex:i];
```

In Objective-C, it is called "you are sending a message (`objectAtIndex:i`) to the array".

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, but hard to tell without your header file declarations, that your problem is you need to #import the file where your class is declared. This is the most common problem when having issues like this. It somehow does not know that it is an NSMutableArray. Also as I noted above you need to assign the value you get back from the array into a typed variable of that class so that you can then access the isChosen property.

Comment: Should be no need to import anything unless he's mucked with the default Xcode settings or is coding in a module that isn't named ".m".